# CGI Script not responding through Wamp

Tags: perl, cgi

I have configure wamp for cgi scripts correctly but it is not running following code and giving following server error on executing.

```
 Bad file descriptor: don't know how to spawn child process: 
   C:/wamp/www/New folder/hello.cgi, referer: http://localhost/New%20folder/
```

My active perl is installed on C:/wamp/www/perl
here is code:

```
 #!C:\wamp\bin\perl.exe -w
 print "Hello World.\n";
```

Comment: i have tried this also

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not pay attention to `#!` lines.  You need to make sure that your file extension (`.cgi` in your case, or `.pl` more commonly) is associated with your perl executable in the registry.

---

More info:

There are two ways to run a perl program/script, one is to execute perl directly with the file name of the main program/script as a parameter:

```
C:\wamp\bin\perl.exe mydir\myprog.pl
```

Don't **ever** do this in the cgi directory of your web server.

The other way to execute a program is to just name the file to be run and depend on the OS's built in method to find the right program to run it.

```
mydir\myprog.pl
```

On a *nix OS, the 1st two bytes of the file are analyzed to determine what to do with it, if those two bytes are the equivalent of the ASCII string `#!` then the file is treated as text, & the rest of the 1st line is read with the expectation that it will contain the path to the file's interpreter.

On a Windows OS, the file extension is used to search the registry for the path to the interpreter associated with that file type.